# burning CDs or DVDs and ISO files in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: iso, dvd, cd, burning

I am running ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I notice there is no cd/dvd burner.  I write click on a file and there is the option to open with disk image writer.  I can write to a hard drive but not to the CD/DVD.

When I copy files to the CD burner in the first place, they are present there but there is no option to write or burn them.  My DVD burner is a LG M Disc and it works in Windows.  I am able to see files in ubuntu from this reader.

Having said this, I never installed any CD burner software like Brasario.  It looks like in 20.04 LTS there is a CD writer but aparrently not in 18.04.

Comment: Brasero is very efficient and user friendly. Where is the problem exactly ?

Answer (score 4):

CD/DVD burning softwares are not included by default in recent versions of Ubuntu, as many recent computers do not have a optical drive, and their usage is declining.

However, many burners are available for free in the Ubuntu repositories. You can use `Brasero`, a free and efficient CD/DVD burner. Here's how to install it.

**GUI Method:** Open Software Center, and search for `Brasero`. Click the install button, and enter your password.

**Command line method:** Open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo apt install brasero
```

It will ask for your password, but the password won't show up in the terminal for security. Press enter after entering your password.